# Changing one row into x rows by 10 columns

Tags: excel, vba

```
**'Dim raport As Worksheet
'Dim daty As String
'Dim lcolumn As Long
'Dim mycolaaa As String
'Dim dataT As Variant
'Set raport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
'raport.Activate
'lcolumn = raport.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'daty = ("A1:xy1")

'With raport
'raport.Range(daty).Select
'End With
'Selection.Copy
'dataT = Application.Transpose(Data)
'With tarws
'CopyRangeAddress = .Range("A2:A100").Address
   ' .Range(CopyRangeAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '.Range(CopyRangeAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    '.Range(CopyRangeAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
'End With

srcws.Activate       

'With srcws
    '.Range(sortrangeaddress).Select
'End With
'Selection.Copy
'Paste the Sort Range on to the target worksheet
'The CopyRangeAddress will be A1 through the last Row
'and column 2 -- so something like A1:B2
'With tarws
    'CopyRangeAddress = .Range(.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol), _
            '.Cells(pasteRow + lrow - 2, 2)).Address
    '.Range(CopyRangeAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '.Range(CopyRangeAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    '.Range(CopyRangeAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
'End With**
```

How to add "daty" cells instead of sortrangeadress? It is data from source worksheet in one row as header of below cells that you helped me with transposing. Thank you a lot for previous answers!

Comment: Please share some test data and the your coding attempts to solve this and explain where stuck.

Comment: to format code properly, indent your first line as well (you can highlight and click the {} or Ctrl-K to indent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your pictures it looks like you are attempting to un-pivot a pivot table.  Your best bet to tackle this is to create smaller ranges for each "date" groupings.  The code below provides an example of how to move through the groupings.

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub Example()
    Const firstDataCell As Long = 3 'Column C
    Const columnsInDataGroup As Long = 10
    Const DataRowStart As Long = 2 'Row 2

    'Worksheet with the source data
    Dim srcWs As Worksheet
    Set srcWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Worksheet to write data to
    Dim tarWs As Worksheet
    Set tarWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Get the last row of data
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = LastRow(srcWs)

    'Get the last column containing data
    Dim lCol As Long
    lCol = LastColumn(srcWs)

    'This are the first columns you seem to
    'want to sort the data on
    Dim SortRangeAddress As String
    SortRangeAddress = "A2:B" & Trim(CStr(lRow))

    'This variable will contain the address of
    'each Date Data Group as your macro
    'loops across the columns
    Dim dateDataGroupRangeAddress As String

    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim pasteRow As Long: pasteRow = 1
    Dim pasteCol As Long: pasteCol = 1
    Dim CopyRangeAddress As String

    For col = firstDataCell To lCol Step columnsInDataGroup
        'Copy the Sort Range from the source worksheet to
        'the target worksheet.
        With srcWs
            .Range(SortRangeAddress).Select
        End With
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste the Sort Range on to the target worksheet
        'The CopyRangeAddress will be A1 through the last Row
        'and column 2 -- so something like A1:B2
        With tarWs
            CopyRangeAddress = .Range(.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol), _
                    .Cells(pasteRow + lRow - 2, 2)).Address
            .Range(CopyRangeAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

        'Copy the next source date data group. The width of the selection
        'is determine by columnsInDataGroup constant set above less 1
        'Think of the first .Cells as 1 and the second .Cells as
        'columnsInDataGroup - 1.
        With srcWs
            dateDataGroupRangeAddress = .Range(.Cells(DataRowStart, col), _
                    .Cells(lRow, col + columnsInDataGroup - 1)).Address
            .Range(dateDataGroupRangeAddress).Select
        End With
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste the next source date date group to the target worksheet
        'CopyRangeAddress here will move 2 columns over from the
        'Start of the sort data range (Columns A & B) to start the
        'paste in column C
        With tarWs
            CopyRangeAddress = .Range(.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol + 2), _
                    .Cells(pasteRow + lRow - 2, columnsInDataGroup + 2)).Address
            .Range(CopyRangeAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
        pasteRow = pasteRow + lRow - 1

    Next col

End Sub

Function LastRow(ByRef sh As Worksheet)

    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).row

End Function

Function LastColumn(ByRef sh As Worksheet)

    LastColumn = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for that code! Could you please explain how to change specified name of tarws for function that could create new sheet with name from srcws + "r" or something different? I am trying to connect those two codes into one.

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to create a new worksheet and then name it using the source worksheet as a base name.  There are many examples you can find by googling.  A [Code VBA](http://codevba.com/excel/add_worksheet.htm#.W745iPYpDcs) has a great example.